# Hold inline block until browser width reach certain width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two inline-block element which is `dt` and `<div class="details">`.

They appeared side by side when view from large screen.

When browser resized, `<div class="details">` will drop to next line cause it's an inline element, right.

My question is, can the image `dt` be resized first (when browser resized - not reaching browser edge)? So my second inline-block element `<div class="details">` wont drop just yet.

When the image reach certain width (let's say 200px),(or, certain browser width) then `<div class="details">` drop to next line.

I want to achieve this because, by default `<div class="details">` will drop to next line when touching `dt` and then leave this gap between `dt` and browser edge.

Hope somebody can point me how to do it maybe with some JQuery. Thank You.

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt><img src="Image Source"/></dt>
    <div class="details">
        <dd>Name</dd>
        <dd>Price</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/pandaktuai/SxbHd/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/87vtr/)

1. `dd` must be nested directly inside the `dl` element. (delete the `div`), even if it works it's not correct.
2. your vertical aligning don't work. (so I didn't implement it in my fiddle)

this solution uses `calc()` (CSS3), so if you need older browser support, use a script instead.
also, If you can use a regular layout (`div`s instead of the list layout) it can be done using the CSS table layout.

**HTML:**

```
<dl>
    <dt><img src="http://i230.photobucket.com/albums/ee189/pandaktuai/img-fluid.jpg" /></dt>
    <dd>Name<br />Price</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

dl
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
    dl:after
    {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }

dt, dd
{
    float: left;
}

dt
{
    max-width: calc(100% - 215px);
}

    dt img
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

dd
{
    padding: 5%;
    color: white;
    min-width: 215px;
}
```

Comment: avrahamcool, much appreciated,I'm gonna try your suggestion first and see how it work out,if it don't, I think I need to post some pics to better explained it.